# In R,Computing average from 1000 replications

Tags: r, replicate

I'm trying to do a test 1000 times, sum all of the answers and divide all of it by 1000.

I'm trying something like this but it is not working ,but it's only giving me the value for it doing it 1 time.

```r
for(i in 1:1000) {
  x <- sample(1:500, 30, replace = F)

  mhat <- stimateM <- 2*mean(x) - 1
  y <- abs(mhat-500)
  value =+ y
}
```

Comment: Well, you are overwriting your result. It does compute the values 1000 times, but you only retain the last one. Try capturing the output in a container defined before the loop.

Comment: And just to be clear, if `value =+ y` is supposed to be `value = value + y` (i.e. `value += y`), the `+=` construct does not exist in `R`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a more `R`-ish solution that doesn't use a loop:

```
x <- replicate(1000, sample.int(500,30,replace=F))
y <- abs(2*colMeans(x)-501)

sumValue = sum(y)
divValue = mean(y)
```

`replicate` will give us the desired output as a matrix, and we can then use the vectorized function `colMeans`.

This method will perform much better as your number of replicates increases:

```
loopSoln <- function(N) {
  value = list()
  for(i in 1:N) {
    x=sample(1:500,30,replace=F)
    mhat=stimateM=2*mean(x)-1
    y=abs(mhat-500)
    value[i]=y
  }
  sumValue = sum(unlist(value))
  divValue = sumValue/N
}

replicateSoln <- function(N) {
  x <- replicate(1000, sample.int(500,30,replace=F))
  y <- abs(2*colMeans(x)-501)
  sumValue = sum(y)
  divValue = mean(y)
}

(ltimes <- sapply(c(1e2,1e3,1e4,1e5), function(N) system.time(loopSoln(N))[3]))
## elapsed elapsed elapsed elapsed 
##   0.002   0.014   0.158   2.009 

(rtimes <- sapply(c(1e2,1e3,1e4,1e5), function(N) system.time(replicateSoln(N))[3]))
## elapsed elapsed elapsed elapsed 
##   0.007   0.011   0.007   0.010 

plot(ltimes~I(2:5), type = 'l', col = 2, xlab = "log_10 number of replicates", ylab = "elapsed time (sec)")
lines(rtimes~I(2:5), col = 4)
legend("topleft", lty = 1, col = c(2,4), 
  legend = c("Loop", "replicate + rowMeans"))
```

[image: Benchmarks]

Answer (score 0):

To build off of coffeinjunky's suggestion, here is an example of defining the container outside of loop, then adding the simulated value inside the loop, then summing and dividing all of the values outside the loop at the end.

```
value = list()

for(i in 1:1000){

  x=sample(1:500,30,replace=F)

  mhat=stimateM=2*mean(x)-1
  y=abs(mhat-500)
  value[i]=y

}

sumValue = sum(unlist(value))
divValue = sumValue/1000
```

Comment: Thank you,it seems to be working. Could you clarify why do I need to start the value as list()?

Comment: Usually never a good idea to create a result `value = list()` and then 'append' to it, e.g., `value[i] = ...`; instead use `replicate(1000, {...})` or similar.

Comment: Martin, could you show me an example of what would go inside the brackets of replicate.